# Recuperar estatísticas de um site

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics-api

Gostaria de saber como recuperar estatísticas do Google Analytics no meu site em tempo real.

A ideia é recuperar dados como por exemplo quantos visitantes eu tenho online no momento em determinada página ou quantas pessoas já visualizaram determinada página no dia atual.

Alguém poderia compartilhar uma forma de fazer isso com javascript e-ou se necessário PHP? Se puderem dar um exemplo simples, agradesso muito!

Comment: Relacinonado: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839430/real-time-visitors-from-google-analytics-how-to-get-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu gastei um tempinho para "traduzir" as informações do [tutorial básico do Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api) e assim quem sabe ajudar.

Basicamente a ideia é a seguinte:

- A sua aplicação Web (eu fiz em Javascript, mas você pode fazer em PHP, Java ou Python; vide a página original do tutorial para exemplos) precisa ser autorizada pelo usuário do Google (o perfil, ou a conta do GMail, digamos assim) a acessar as informações das contas do Analytics relacionadas ao usuário logado.
- Uma vez autorizada, você pode acessar uma conta específica, e por meio de uma estrutura (bastante confusa, há de se admitir) de *web properties* e perfis você tem acesso aos dados de interesse na forma de um relatório em JSON.
- Nesse exemplo eu aproveitei e utilizei o [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/?hl=pt-br) para exibir as "Visitas por País" (porque Google Charts é bem fácil e muuuuuiiiiitooo legal! hehehe)

Então, vamos lá.

**Autorizando o Acesso**

A primeira coisa a fazer é criar um projeto para definir a sua aplicação. Esse projeto é na verdade a "aplicação" que solicita a autorização do usuário, e é algo bem parecido com o que o Facebook faz - de fato, aqui também se utiliza o OAuth 2.0 para gerenciar os tokens de acesso.

Para isso, você precisa acessar o [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com) e criar o seu projeto. Não vou gastar muito tempo com um passo a passo de como fazer isso (tem tudo no tutorial original!), mas o fundamental é dar um nome para o projeto (eu chamei de "Teste") e depois ir em "Credentials" para criar o ID do cliente e a chave pública de API. O ID do cliente deve ser para uma aplicação Web (*Web Application*) e deve indicar o(s) endereço(s) de origem para o Javascript, e a chave pública de API deve ser para Navegador (*Browser*), pois nesse exemplo eu estou executando código no cliente (se você usar PHP, por exemplo, escolha chave API para Servidor). A imagem abaixo ilustra a edição do ID do cliente (note que eu usei o site do Instituto de Matemática e Estátistica na Universidade de São Paulo apenas porque eu fiz o teste na minha página pessoal lá - é o único local que eu tenho disponível para esse fim - mas as informações do Analytics serão carregadas de uma das contas do meu perfil do Google e não do site do IME-USP).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**IMPORTANTE**: Você também precisa garantir que o Google Analytics esteja habilitado (na opção "APIs", item "*Analytics API*" e o seu projeto precisa ter um nome na tela de consentimento que será exibida ao usuário (campo "*Product name*" na opção "*Consent Screen*").

Tendo feito isso, o tutorial original do Google demonstra como solicitar a autorização para essa aplicação. O primeiro passo é definir um arquivo HTML com alguns botões (um para solicitar a autorização e outro para requisitar a consulta) e que carrega as bibliotecas necessárias. No HTML a seguir há também um parágrafo e um div com o gráfico do Google Charts que eu adicionei a mais.

> Arquivo Teste.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Teste da API do Google Analytics (com Google Charts!)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Botões para interação do usuário. -->
    <button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">Autorizar</button><br/>
    <button id="make-api-call-button" style="visibility: hidden">Consultar Visitas</button>

    <!-- Título e gráfico para exibição dos resultados -->
    <p id="report-title" style="visibility: hidden"></p>
    <div id="report-chart" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; visibility: hidden"></div>

    <!-- Arquivos Javascript com o código de exemplo. -->
    <script src="teste_auth.js"></script>
    <script src="teste.js"></script>

    <!-- Carrega a biblioteca cliente do Google Analytics. O parâmetro 'onload' especifica a função de callback. -->
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>

    <!-- API para o Google Charts -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
          google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

O arquivo Javascript inicialmente importante é o `Teste_auth.js` que contém o código para tratamento da autorização (é ele também que exibe/esconde os botões conforme o usuário autoriza ou não). Note que há três variáveis iniciais, sendo que as duas primeiras devem conter o número do ID de Cliente (*Client ID*, indicado na imagem anterior por uma faixa em preto) e a chave da API Pública (*API Key*) que você criou para o seu projeto.

> Arquivo Teste_auth.js

```js
var clientId = '999999999999';
var apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXX-XXXXXXXXXXX';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly';

// Função chamada após o carregamento da biblioteca cliente do Google Analytics
function handleClientLoad() {
    // 1. Configura a Chave da API (API Key)
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);

    // 2. Chama a função de verificação de autorização do usuário.
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
}

// Função de requisição da autorização do usuário
function checkAuth() {
    // Chama o serviço do Google Accounts para determinar o estado de autorização do usuário atual.
    // Passa a resposta para a função de callback handleAuthResult
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult) {
        // O usuário autorizou o acesso
        // Carrega o cliente do Google Analytics.
        loadAnalyticsClient();
    }
    else {
        // O usuário não autorizou o acesso
        handleUnAuthorized();
    }
}

// Função para tratamento de aceitação de autorização pelo usuário
function handleAuthorized() {
    var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
    var makeApiCallButton = document.getElementById('make-api-call-button');

    // Exibe o botão 'Consultar Visitas' e esconde o botão 'Autorizar'
    makeApiCallButton.style.visibility = '';
    authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    // Quando o botão 'Consultar Visitas' é clicado, chama a função makeAapiCall (que está no outro arquivo .js)
    makeApiCallButton.onclick = makeApiCall;
}

// Função para tratamento de negação de autorização pelo usuário
function handleUnAuthorized() {
    var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
    var makeApiCallButton = document.getElementById('make-api-call-button');

    // Exibe o botão 'Autorizar' e esconde o botão 'Consultar Visitas'
    makeApiCallButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';

    // Quando o botão 'Autorizar' é clicado, chama a função handleAuthClick
    authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
}

// Callback do clique no botão 'Autorizar'
function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
    return false;
}

// Função para carregamento e autorização do cliente do Google Analytics
function loadAnalyticsClient() {
    // Carrega o cliente autorizado do Google Analytics, definindo a função handleAuthorized como callback
    gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3', handleAuthorized);
}
```

O código tem alguns comentários, mas deve ser auto-explicativo. A ideia é que ele faz a requisição de autorização, e se autorizado pelo usuário exibe o botão "Consultar Visitas", que executa um código no próximo arquivo.

**Fazendo a Consulta**

Esse próximo código contém a execução da consulta propriamente dita (e a preparação do gráfico bacana com o mapa usando o Google Charts! hehe). O que eu acho necessário explicar é o seguinte:

- O meu perfil do Google está atrelado a algumas "contas" que eu tenho, entre elas o meu site pessoal (www.luiz.vieira.nom.br, feito no Google Sites) e dois blogs. Todas elas estão com o Analytics habilitado (afinal, os dados precisam estar sendo coletados, certo? :) Caso você não saiba, isso é configurado no [site do Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)). O código a seguir basicamente pega a primeira conta encontrada (no meu caso, o site pessoal) e consulta APENAS DESSA CONTA as visitas por país.

> Arquivo Teste.js

```js
// Função para execução da consulta (callback do clique no botão 'Consultar Visitas')
function makeApiCall() {
    queryAccounts();
}

// Função de consulta propriamente dita
function queryAccounts() {
    // Obtém a lista de todas as contas do Google Analytics para o usuário
    gapi.client.analytics.management.accounts.list().execute(handleAccounts);
}

// Função de tratamento das contas do usuário
function handleAccounts(results) {
    if (!results.code) {
        if (results && results.items && results.items.length) {

            // Pega a primeira conta encontrada
            var firstAccountId = results.items[0].id;

            // Faz a consulta das web properties da conta
            queryWebproperties(firstAccountId);
        }
        else {
            alert('Não há contas do Google Analytics para esse usuário!');
        }
    }
    else {
        alert('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar consultar as contas do Google Analytics: ' + results.message);
    }
}

// Função de consulta das web properties para o dado ID de conta
function queryWebproperties(accountId) {
    // Faz a consulta usando o id da conta
    gapi.client.analytics.management.webproperties.list({'accountId': accountId}).execute(handleWebproperties);
}

// Função de tratamento das web properties
function handleWebproperties(results) {
    if (!results.code) {
        if (results && results.items && results.items.length) {

          // Pega a primeira conta encontrada
          var firstAccountId = results.items[0].accountId;

          // Pega a primeira web property encontrada
          var firstWebpropertyId = results.items[0].id;

          // Consulta as views (perfis) para a conta e web property dadas
          queryProfiles(firstAccountId, firstWebpropertyId);

        }
        else {
            alert('Não há web properties para esse usuário.');
        }
    }
    else {
        alert('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar acessar as web properties: ' + results.message);
    }
}

// Função de consulta aos Perfis para os dados IDs de conta e de web property
function queryProfiles(accountId, webpropertyId) {
    // Obtém a lista de todas as views (perfis) para a web property e conta
    gapi.client.analytics.management.profiles.list({
      'accountId': accountId,
      'webPropertyId': webpropertyId
    }).execute(handleProfiles);
}

// Função de tratamento dos perfis
function handleProfiles(results) {
    if (!results.code) {
        if (results && results.items && results.items.length) {

            // Obtém o primeiro perfil
            var firstProfileId = results.items[0].id;

            // Consulta usando o Reporting API
            queryCoreReportingApi(firstProfileId);

        }
        else {
            console.log('Não há perfis para esse usuário.');
        }
    }
    else {
        alert('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar consultar os perfis: ' + results.message);
    }
}

// Função de execução do relatório (reporting)
function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId) {
    // Usa o objeto de Serviço do Analytics para consultar a API de Reporting
    gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
        'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
        'start-date': '2010-01-01',
        'end-date': '2014-04-09',
        'metrics': 'ga:visits',
        'dimensions': 'ga:country',
        'sort': '-ga:visits'
    }).execute(handleCoreReportingResults);
}

// Função de tratamento do retorno do relatório consultado
function handleCoreReportingResults(results) {
    if (results.error) {
        alert('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar consultar os dados do Google Analytics via reporting API: ' + results.message);
    }
    else {
        showResults(results);
    }
}

// Função para exibição bonitinha dos resultados
function showResults(results) {
    if (results.rows && results.rows.length) {
        var reportTitle = document.getElementById('report-title');
        var reportChart = document.getElementById('report-chart');

        reportTitle.innerHTML = "<h1>Visitas por Pais para o perfil '" + results.profileInfo.profileName + "'</h1>";
        reportTitle.style.visibility = '';

        var data = [['Country', 'Visits']];
        for(var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            data.push([results.rows[i][0], parseInt(results.rows[i][6])]);
        }
        console.log(data);
        data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

        var options = {
            colorAxis: {colors: ['yellow', 'green', 'blue']}
        };

        reportChart.style.visibility = '';
        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('report-chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    else {
        alert('Não há visitas reportadas.');
    }
}
```

O resultado é um mapa como o a seguir, que é interativo (mova o mouse sobre os países para visualizar os valores):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**ATENÇÃO**: Lembre-se que eu executei esse código a partir do meu site pessoal na USP (e que foi devidamente autorizado como origem do Javascript na criação da aplicação no Google Developers Console).

**Concluindo**

Bom, eu usei como exemplo a consulta das Visitas por País, mas você pode fazer inúmeras consultas distintas alterando os parâmetros de `gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get` (na função `queryCoreReportingApi`. Veja [nesse site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/common-queries) as consultas mais comuns, com exemplos práticos que podem até mesmo ser executados online no [Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) do Google.

Sobre o mapa, você também pode configurar parâmetros como cores, tamanho, região exibida (dá pra exibir só a América do Sul, por exemplo) e formas de exibição dos dados (por colorização do mapa, por marcadores, etc). Consulte [esse link](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) para detalhes sobre esse mapa em especial (embora o Google Charts, linkado lá no começo, tenha um monte de outras opções bacanas!).

E é isso ai. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ajudou e muito! Ainda não realizei todos os testes, mas li e aparentemente não vou ter dificuldades para me basear no seus exemplos. Muito bem explicado e exemplificado! Obrigado Luiz!

Answer (score 1):

A Google lançou sua **Real Time API**. Com ela voce pode pegar facilmente visitantes em tempo real. Alem de outros indicadores do Google Analytics.

Endereço: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/

Ela é bem similar à API existente: Google Analytics API. Para começar o desenvolvimento dê uma checada nesse endereço: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/devguide

Comment: Acho que isso vai ajudar bastante embora eu ache as documentações do Google muito confusas ^^. Obrigado!

Comment: @DiegoLopesLima confusas e muitas vezes desatualizadas e/ou com detalhes essenciais faltando.

Answer (score 0):

Se você pretende que outras pessoas possam ver estatísticas do Google Analytics sobre o seu site, o melhor é acessar a API do Google Analytics a partir do servidor para não expor a credenciais de autenticação da sua conta a terceiros quando isso fosse feito por JavaScript.

Se quer uma solução pronta, tem a classe de PHP [SmartGAPI](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6837-PHP-Display-site-statistics-from-Google-Analytics.html) que acessa a API do Google Analytics e gera JavaScript para usar AJAX para que esse acesso a API seja feito através do servidor em PHP, e no lado do browser apenas os dados que importam são mostrados, como pode ver no exemplo desta imagem.

[image: Examplo do uso da classe SmartGAPI]